# C++ default constructor: string params vs string params()

Tags: c++, default-constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is no parentheses on a constructor with no arguments a language standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318650/is-no-parentheses-on-a-constructor-with-no-arguments-a-language-standard)

Can anyone explain why these line don't give me an error:

```
string params;
params+="d";
```

but these lines:

```
string params();
params+="d";
```

give me this error: error C2659: '+=' : function as left operand

Comment: See [Most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not object:

```
 string params();
```

This is function returning string:

```
 string params();
```

Like this:

```
 string params(void);
```

So the error now is obvious: **function** as left operand

This problem has own name: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: so string params() is not an object but string params("word") is an object?

Comment: @kakush Yes - "word" is not type - it is value - so it is object. When compiler is in doubt if the expression is function declaration or object - it always select function declaration. In your example with "word" - there is no doubt.

Comment: thanks @PiotrNycz . so if I want to use string's empty const' how do i do that?

Comment: @kakush: you write `string params;`, which calls the class's default constructor if it has one declared (`string` does). If you want some type `T` that might not have a constructor at all (for instance built-in types), you can write `T t = T();` provided that it's copyable (or movable in C++11). If you have a type that *either* has a declared default constructor *or* is copyable, but you don't know which, then in C++03 you have a problem. In C++11 you can write `T t{};` to value-initialize anything.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case with the

```
string params;
```

creates a string instance using a default constructor.

In the second case the

```
string params();
```

creates a pointer to a *function returning string*. On that type the *operator+=(const string&)* is apparently not defined.

Yes, it is a bit confusing feature of the language because when you use not default constructor, you could really write e.g.

```
string params("d");
```